# trouble appending hash value ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, append, concatenation

I'm writing a program which takes input, stores it as a hash and sorts the values.

I'm having trouble comparing a current hash value with a variable.

Sample Input: 
 
3 
 
A 1  
B 3 
C 5 
A 2 
B 7 
C 2

Sample Output:

A 1 2 
B 3 7 
C 2 5

Everything works apart from this part, and I'm unsure why.

```
 if values.key?(:keys)
        if values[keys] >= val
              values.store(keys,val.prepend(val + " "))
        else
              values.store(keys,val.concat(" " + val))
        end
      else
        values.store(keys,val)
    end
      i = i + 1
    end
```

Rest of code:

```
#get amount of records
size = gets.chomp
puts size
size = size.to_i
values = Hash.new(0)
i = 0
while i < (size * 2)
  text = gets.chomp
#split string and remove space
  keys = text.split[0]
  val = text.split[1]

#check if key already exists,
# if current value is greater than new value append new value to end
# else put at beginning of current value

  if values.key?(:keys)
    if values[keys] >= val
          values.store(keys,val.prepend(val + " "))
    else
          values.store(keys,val.concat(" " + val))
    end
  else
    values.store(keys,val)
end
  i = i + 1
end

#sort hash by key
values = values.sort_by { |key, value| key}
#output hash values
values.each{|key, value|
    puts "#{key}:#{value}"
}
```

Could anyone help me out? It would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that there are two mistakes in your code. Here is the fixed version:

```
if values.key?(keys) 
  if values[keys] >= val 
    values.store(keys,values[keys].prepend(val + " ")) 
  else 
    values.store(keys,values[keys].concat(" " + val)) 
  end 
else 
  values.store(keys,val) 
end
```

- The `if` statement was always evaluating as `false`, because you were looking for hash key named `:keys` (which is a [`Symbol`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Symbol.html)), not the variable you've declared named `keys`.
- Even with that fixed, there was a second hidden bug: You were storing a incorrect new hash value. `val.concat(" " + val)` would give you results like `A 2 2`, not `A 1 2`, since it's using the new value twice, not the original value.

With that said, you code is still very confusing to read... Your variables are `size`, `i`, `text`, `val`, `values`, `key` and `keys`. It would have been a lot easier to understand with clearer variable names, if nothing else :)

Here is a slightly improved version, without changing the overall structure of your code:

```
puts "How may variables to loop through?" 
result_length = gets.chomp.to_i 
result = {} 

puts "Enter #{result_length * 2} key-value pairs:" 
(result_length * 2).times do 
  input = gets.chomp 
  input_key = input.split[0] 
  input_value = input.split[1] 

  #check if key already exists, 
  # if current value is greater than new value append new value to end 
  # else put at beginning of current value 

  if result.key?(input_key) 
    if result[input_key] >= input_value 
      result[input_key] = "#{input_value} #{result[input_key]}" 
    else 
      result[input_key] = "#{result[input_key]} #{input_value}" 
    end 
  else 
    result[input_key] = input_value 
  end 
end 

#sort hash by key 
result.sort.to_h 

#output hash result 
result.each{|key, value| 
  puts "#{key}:#{value}" 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I've been scratching my head at this for ages haha

Comment: If you want to improve this further, then a far more sensible data structure would be something like this: `{"A" => [1, 2], "B" => [3, 7], "C" => [5, 2]}`. You can then do any reordering of keys without messing around with string manipulation. (For example, your current version will break for inputs `>= 10`, or if you assign 3 or more values to a key.)

Answer (score 1):

```ruby
h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }
input = ['A 1', 'B 3', 'C 5', 'A 2', 'B 7', 'C 2'].join("\n")
input.each_line { |x| h[$1] << $2 if x =~ /^(.*?)\s+(.*?)$/ }

h.keys.sort.each do |k|
  puts ([k] + h[k].sort).join(' ')
end

# A 1 2
# B 3 7
# C 2 5
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a more Ruby-ish way to write your code :

```
input = "A 1
B 3
C 5
A 2
B 7
C 2"

input.scan(/[A-Z]+ \d+/)
     .map{ |str| str.split(' ') }
     .group_by{ |letter, _| letter }
     .each do |letter, pairs|
  print letter
  print ' '
  puts pairs.map{ |_, number| number }.sort.join(' ')
end
#=> 
# A 1 2
# B 3 7
# C 2 5
```